# Buttons on Layout with Webview

Tags: java, android, layout, button, click

I cannot figure out why these 2 buttons are not working, i have a layout file inwhich is created when the user selects a certain theme in my application. With the layout it has a webview it has 2 buttons to goback and goforward.

```
   <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Back" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/button_blue" 
    style="@style/ButtonText">
  </Button>

  <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button2" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
    style="@style/ButtonText" 
    android:text="Forward">
 </Button>


  <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.12" >
```

This is not the entire layout file, but here is the bit of stuff i am working with for the webview and the 2 buttons, now inside my main activity here is my button code.

```
      @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (Prefs.theme.equals("Theme1"))
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    else if (Prefs.theme.equals("Theme2"))
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    else if (Prefs.theme.equals("Theme3"))
        setContentView(R.layout.main3);
    else setContentView(R.layout.main);



    btnForward=(Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
    btnBackward=(Button) findViewById (R.id.button2);
    btnForward.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnBackward.setOnClickListener(this);


    // more code within on create .....

// Later in the code 

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button1:
            WebViewClientDemoActivity.web.goBack();
           break;

        case R.id.button2:
            WebViewClientDemoActivity.web.goForward();
           break;
    }
```

//

I problem im having is by default it loads main.xml not main3 (which is were the 2 buttons are)

LogCat Errors

```
  07-27 16:00:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(547): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  07-27 16:00:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(547): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity       ComponentInfo{com.jaisonbrooks.enlighten/com.jaisonbrooks.enlighten.WebViewClientDemoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
  07-27 16:00:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
  07-27 16:00:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
  07-27 16:00:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
  07-27 16:00:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(547):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
  07-27 16:00:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(547):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  07-27 16:00:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(547):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  07-27 16:00:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
  07-27 16:00:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(547):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  07-27 16:00:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(547):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  07-27 16:00:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(547):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
  07-27 16:00:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(547):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
  07-27 16:00:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(547):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  07-27 16:00:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(547): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  07-27 16:00:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(547):    at com.jaisonbrooks.enlighten.WebViewClientDemoActivity.onCreate(WebViewClientDemoActivity.java:75)
  07-27 16:00:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(547):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
  07-27 16:00:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(547):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
  07-27 16:00:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(547):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: did you override the method onClick(View v) ??? ( not onButtonClicked() ) . second thing  , did you set the onClickListener for your buttons ?

Comment: I have only done what is coded above, so using your example would it look like this  `@Overide     public void onClick(View v) {
          
    switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button1:
            WebViewClientDemoActivity.web.goBack();
           break;
        case R.id.button2:
            WebViewClientDemoActivity.web.goForward();
           break;
    }`

Comment: yes thats it , and before , you should set onClickListeners to your buttons like this : btnForward.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: Ok im working on it , how would it look, could you update my code, if thats not to much to ask.

Comment: see my answer , i will give you an example how to implement it

Comment: I added this to it, but i got errors on (this) due to syntax error,   `button1.setOnClickListener(this);    button2.setOnClickListener(this);`

Comment: i think you set the listener somewhere in an inner class implementation, try this : button1.setOnClickListener(YourActivityName.this);

Comment: IM getting this error `yntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead`  I updated my code with what i did.

Comment: see my answer , you don't need the method onButtonClick , you should rename it to onClick(View v )

Comment: I have changed it to what you see, do you know how i would go about writing code to when a spefic layout file is set, in mya case main3.xml where the 2 buttons are located. will be created and be used just when that layout is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your onCreate  method find your buttons by ids :

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button btnForward;
Button btnBackward;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnForward=(Button) findViewById (R.id.btnForward);
        btnBackward=(Button) findViewById (R.id.btnBackward);

        //set listeners
        btnForward.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnBackward.setOnClickListener(this);

        // your code here .... 
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v ) {
     switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnBackward:
            WebViewClientDemoActivity.web.goBack();
           break;
        case R.id.btnForward:
            WebViewClientDemoActivity.web.goForward();
           break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Alright i have impletment this in my code, BTW thank you for helping me, the only problem im having is inside my code area where i have all my other code, the `R.id.btnForward` say i need to insert a } however under the button click stuff i have my webview stuff and below that a alert dialog. so i guess im having problems where to insert a } without throwing all my code in errors.

Comment: However after i have impletement the above code my application has force closed. i have updated the logcat above

Comment: I have updated my source code with what i have impletement of yours. will you take a look at it

Comment: the error that you have is in  the onCreate() method , exaclty  at the line 75 (WebViewClientDemoActivity.java:75) , could you give us the line of code in line 75 ? i think that the variable Prefs is null , where did you instanciate it ?

Comment: This code did resolve the issue, my themes on the applications where causing the code not to work

Answer (score 1):

It should work. Make sure you don't have 2 buttons with the same `@id`.
It's a common issue when you multiplicate your buttons from one. (copy/paste)

Comment: they both are different as you can see in the code, i do not have a setOnclickListner setup do i need that and if i do where would a implement it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button 
android:id="@+id/button1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:text="Back" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:background="@drawable/button_blue" 
style="@style/ButtonText" />

<Button 
android:id="@+id/button2" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
style="@style/ButtonText" 
android:text="Forward" />
```

try this.

then later in java code, do this

```
 Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
 btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
 {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
         WebViewClientDemoActivity.web.goForward();
    }
 });


 Button btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
 btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
 {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
         WebViewClientDemoActivity.web.goBack();
    }
 });
```

Comment: I have tried it and still doesnt work, no force closes are errors, just when the buttons are click nothing happens.

Comment: oh i got downvoted for not understanding your question. neat.

lemme edit and see if i can get some karma out of it.

Comment: I have tried you code, and either i have to insert a additional `}` to close my main acitivty, which i still my my onresume onstop, etc below it, if that is ok, i get error with the first part `Button btnNext = (Button)` etc. and the only fix it says is to remove. Thanks for your help

Comment: can you post the error? somehow i'm guessing you need to import android.widget.Button; try pressing ctrl+o if in Eclipse and see if that fixes it.

the other error that pops into my mind is that R.id.button1 cannot be referenced in which case you need to clean your project and rebuild so that the R class gets regenerated and contain the proper id.

Comment: so i tried your code i dont where at inside my activity to place it,

Comment: ....

you can try in onCreate() or preferably, somewhere AFTER the spot you called setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_file_that_you_posted);

which could very well be in onCreate() ... if you're opening this XML in a dialog, you'll need to update it with the dialog's name.


Dialog dialogVar = new Dialog(this);
Button b = (Button) dialogVar.findViewById(R.id.button1) etc...

Comment: This maybe why im having problem and errors launching the app now, but i have 4 layout main files, i have a preference menu where i have a theme list, when i list on the last theme. `theme3` it loads the one and only theme with the 2 buttons in question button1 and button2, is this why im getting errors, due to maybe when its load any other layout file it cannot find the buttons?, if so do you know how to make it so the buttons are only created for use on my main3.xml file instead of any of the others?

Comment: post filenames and file contents please, i'm 9 hours into work waiting for a client for telcon; i don't think i have what it takes right now to figure out by myself where and what you need help with.

i can still fix your bugs though, i just need to see them.

Comment: If you would like to send me a email directly i can sent you some code to review @Shark. if you would like to my email is jaisonbrooks@gmail.com  thanks for help me

Comment: Maybe on monday, i just found out i'm not working tomorrow NOR sunday w00t. take care and try to use logcat more instead of relying on other people's eyes :)

Comment: I have tried to determine the issue and cannot figure it out, i will hopefully hear from you monday,i will see what i can do over the weekend as well. thanks @Shark

Comment: feel free to email me at darksidemetatron (at) gmail dot com. try to gather some logs by that time as it will help us imensely to debug the error. cheers.